# Story identification - Demon sleeps with disabled woman, cures her disability

Tags: story-identification

A man possessed by a demon, or maybe the Devil himself actually, is left alone with a woman who is severly disabled. They have sex and by the end, she is no longer disabled.

I think this might be an older British movie, from the 70s perhaps.

I remember it being very short though, too short for a movie but I don't think it was an episode of a TV show. The story seems a bit *much* for something like the outer limits.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: What were her disabilities? Is the sex implied or explicitly shown?

Comment: @Richard I'm not sure what her disabilities are, whether they are mental or physical, but she is unable to move her body. And yes, they show the sex but it's not graphic, I'm pretty sure they both remain fully clothed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Possibly the 1976 (although not broadcast until 1987) BBC play [Brimstone and Treacle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brimstone_and_Treacle)?  Sting plays a homeless person who moves in with a couple and their disabled daughter.  When he rapes her, she regains consciousness.  Sting has mentioned that he believes his character is the Devil.

The daughter (and the Devil) can be seen in the trailer below: